# Is this a bug in the Ruby time class when doing relative date arithmetic?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, time, activesupport

Can someone tell me if this is a bug in the ruby time class?

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :021 > now = Time.now
 => Mon Aug 29 03:32:25 -0700 2011 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :022 > raise "This should not fail" if (now + 1.day != now + 1.day.to_i)
RuntimeError: This should not fail
    from (irb):22
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :023 >
```

As you can see I am getting a runtime error and I do not believe that I should be. I recently upgraded the active_support gem which I believe provides this functionality.

Thank you.

** UPDATE **

And, now it works, without any changes other than me going to bed and waking up and rerunning things. This is very strange; The snippet I provided above was directly cut-and-pasted from my terminal window.... I was running against 3.0.10 of activerecord/support/model/etc

Thanks to all for your thoughts on this matter!

Comment: Please also tell us which version of the active_support you're using.

Comment: What do you `require` before that code? I've required "active_record" and "active_support" and I can't access that `day` method.

Answer (score 3):

While `time.to_s` does not include it, a Time object contains milliseconds - and not only that, it contains fractional seconds (with much higher resolution) (see: [Time#subsec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000391)).

`Time.now == Time.now` will already be false, because each call to `now` will take several CPU ticks to complete. Also take a look at [Time#eql?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000343).

> Return true if time and other_time are both Time objects with the same seconds and fractional seconds.

Comment: In this case `now` is a local variable, so `now == now`. Moreover, I'm assuming `1.day` is an integral number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's not a bug in the `Time` class, because the difference seems to be in the `day` method of the `Fixnum` class. Moreover, that is not a method of the original `Fixnum` class; it shall be defined in some file you `require`d before.